# Css style transparent tooltips?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap [tooltips](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) but I can't seem to figure out how to create the cool css transparent tooltips like on the example [site](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips).  Mine just show up as gray tooltips.

Can I set the style via tag attributes or do I have to do this via jquery/js and if so how?

```
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip">tooltip</a>
```

Bootply -> http://www.bootply.com/68686

Comment: Are you using what browser? It should work fine.

Comment: @gustavohenke using chrome...just have the standard tooltip <a> tag as shown above but get the gray standard ones....the cs transparent show up in the same browser when I visit the bootstrap example page.  perhaps I'm missing a .js or css file?

Comment: @gustavohenke  http://www.bootply.com/68686

Comment: Look, I've done it for you: http://www.bootply.com/68688 you're probably missing some JS :/

Comment: I'll put in a answer with some more information I discovered for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips):

```
For performance reasons, the tooltip and popover data-apis are opt in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.
```

That's because you may have *lots* of tooltips in a page, what could kill the performance.

So, basically, you need to put in your JS this:

```
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```